# ignore field in mapping of list

Tags: java, mapstruct

What i want to accomplish is that a field is ingored within a list of a mapper.Here is an example of what i want to achieve.

Following are entities which i abstract out

```
class X {
  private String field1;
  private String field2;
  private List<Y> ys;
}

class Y {
  private String field1;
  private String field2;
}
```

Matching Dto's are made

```
interface XMapper {

   XDto fromXEntity(X source) ;
   
   YDto fromYEntity(Y source) ;

}
```

I can directly ignore a direct field by @Mapping(ignore = true, target = "field2").

When fromXEntity is generated it will map field1, field2 and ys. Now when the list is mapped i want it to ignore field2. How can i accomplish this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Convert interface as abstract class/class and add a list method, iterate through it and call fromXEntity method

```
class XMapper {   
   XDto fromXEntity(X source) ;     
   YDto fromYEntity(Y source) ;

  List<XDto> fromXEntities(List<XDto> list){
     List<XDto> dtos = new  ArrayList<>();
       for(XDto dto : list){
         dtos.add(fromXEntity(dto));
       }
     return dtos;
  }


}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction. got it solved by creating a default method.